# disable current selection until some value is inputed in the previous selection

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue, disabled-input

I'm working with `BootstrapVue`.

I have following problem. I have a `b-form-input` where I'm searching for my `number` over my `b-form-select`. So I'm selecting 3 values and get a number in my input field and other way around - so it's an **Autofill**.

This works fine - and because of that I think I don't need to show you the code.

The problem is that I want to disable all selects (instead of the first) till the field before was selected.

I have problem that if I have multiple elements all will be updated. So if I input something in `Input1` in the first element the second `Input` of all other elements will be `!disabled`

**Additional Info**: `IDParent` is a prop!

If you need any additional code, I can update my question!

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="mt-2" v-for="(IDChild, indexChild) in inputs" :key="indexChild">
      <div>
        <div class="mt-2">Number</div>
        <b-form-input type="number" v-model="IDChild.Number" :value="IDChild.Number"></b-form-input>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div class="mt-2">Input 1</div>
        <b-form-select v-model="IDChild.Input1" :value="IDChild.Input1" :options="optionsInput1" @input="searchNumber(IDChild, IDParent, indexChild)"></b-form-select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="mt-2">Input 2</div>
        <b-form-select :disabled="disabledInput2" v-model="IDChild.Input2" :value="IDChild.Input2" :options="optionsInput2" @input="searchNumber(IDChild, IDParent, indexChild)"></b-form-select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="mt-2">Input 3</div>
        <b-form-select :disabled="disabledInput3" v-model="IDChild.Input3" :value="IDChild.Input3" :options="optionsInput3" @input="searchNumber(IDChild, IDParent, indexChild)"></b-form-select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- add new element when button was clicked -->
    <div class="mt-4 mb-5 ml-3 mr-3">
      <b-button @click="addElement"> Add Element </b-button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

my script:

```
<script>
import json from "./json/json.json";

export default {
  name: "Test",

  methods: {
    addElement() {
      this.inputs.push({});
    },

    searchNumber(input, IDParent, indexChild) {
      input.Number = "";

      this.json.forEach((element) => {
        if (
          element.Input1 == input.Input1 &&
          element.Input2 == input.Input2 &&
          element.Input3 == input.Input3 
        ) {
          for (const key of Object.keys(element)) {
            input[key] = element[key];
          }
        }
      });

      if(input.Input1) {
        this.disabledInput2 = false;
      }
      if(input.Input2) {
        this.disabledInput3 = false;
      }
    },
  },

  props: [
    "IDParent",
    ],

  data() {
    return {
      inputs: [{}],
      json: json,
      disabledInput2: true,
      disabledInput3: true,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code where `disabledInput2` and `disabledInput3` are defined? Without us knowing when these Booleans will be set, we can't possibly tell you why they flip unexpected

Comment: updated it - hopefully it's clear now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is a multi-layer model for your data which you can call in your `searchNumber` function and call for your `:disabled` attribute.

In your `v-for="(IDChild, indexChild) in inputs"` you could use `IDChild` or `indexChild` for that. For example you would call `:disabled="disabledInput2[indexChild]"`. That way you would refer to `disabledInput2` with the specific `indexChild`.

You also need to handle this in your function, for example `this.disabledInput2[indexChild] = false;`.

Basically it´s the same as storing multi-layer data in the same object with `v-model`.

---

**EDIT:** Generally Example

I´ve created the following properties for this example. We have `myNumberInput` as an object to handle multiple input fields for numbers. `mySelectionData` provides a simple collection of two objects with 3 selection arrays each. `myDisableData` is the object that will handle multiple `disabled` attributes for this selections:

```
    myNumberInput: {},
    mySelectionData: {
        1: {
            1: [
                { name: "1A", value: 1 }, { name: "2A", value: 2 }, { name: "3A", value: 3 }
            ],
            2: [
                { name: "4A", value: 4 }, { name: "5A", value: 5 }, { name: "6A", value: 6 }
            ],
            3: [
                { name: "7A", value: 7 }, { name: "8A", value: 8 }, { name: "9A", value: 9 }
            ]
        },
        2: {
            1: [
                { name: "1B", value: 11 }, { name: "2B", value: 21 }, { name: "3B", value: 31 }
            ],
            2: [
                { name: "4B", value: 41 }, { name: "5B", value: 51 }, { name: "6B", value: 61 }
            ],
            3: [
                { name: "7B", value: 71 }, { name: "8B", value: 81 }, { name: "9B", value: 91 }
            ]
        }
    },
    myDisableData: {}
```

From the `mySelectionData` object, we will build our `myDisableData` with this function:

```
setupMyDisableData() {
      Object.keys(this.mySelectionData).forEach(parent_key => {
        Object.assign(this.myDisableData, {[parent_key]: {}})
        Object.keys(this.mySelectionData[parent_key]).forEach(child_key => {
          Object.assign(this.myDisableData[parent_key], {[child_key]: true})
        });
      });
    }
```

This will loop trough our "parents", assign their `index` to `myDisableData` and also loop trough the "childs" and assign their `index` to `myDisableData` with the "parent"-`index` as a pointer. After that we have a multi-layer object which is able to provide `diabled=` `true` or `false` for each selection.

The html for this example looks like this:

```
<div v-for="(item,index) in mySelectionData" :key="index">
        <input type="number" v-model="myNumberInput[index]" @input="enableMySelection(index, myNumberInput[index])">
        <div v-for="(child_item, child_index) in item" :key="child_index">
          <select :disabled="myDisableData[index][child_index]">
            <option v-for="(child_option, child_option_index) in child_item" :key="child_option_index" :value="child_option.value">{{child_option.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
```

As I don´t use `BootstrapVue`, my html looks different, but I guess you will get the trick. You simply now refer to the three object by the `index` of "parent" and "child". In this example the function `enableMySelection` will enable a selection depending on the number entered in the `input`. The function looks like this:

```
enableMySelection(parent_index, input_number) {
      Object.keys(this.myDisableData[parent_index]).forEach(child_key => {
        this.myDisableData[parent_index][child_key] = true;
      });
      this.myDisableData[parent_index][input_number] = false;
    }
```

So if you enter "2" in your first input, it will enable the second selection of the first block. If you enter 1 in the second input, it will enable the first selection in the second block.

As I said, this is just a generally example but this should be enough to help you define the structure to handle your multiple inputs and selections.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying helping me out! - I've change everything to ```this.disabledInputX[indexChild]``` but right now everything is enabled - I think it's because of my ```data``` - how should I write it in there? Because logically ```disabledInputX[indexChild]: true``` is not working out..

Comment: @B0BBY Currently you have `disabledInput2: true`, but it needs to be an object or array to store the data. As I don´t know the structure of your data and don´t use `BootstrapVue`, I edited my answer with a generally example.